# Reordering sql query by elements with most others associated

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with two columns, A and B.
To each element in A, there corresponds one or more elements in B.
I want to re-order the table so that I have on top the elements in A to which there are associated the most elements in B.

Example:

```
Car     Blue
Home    Red
Home    Pink
Car     Yellow
Home    White
Bike    Blue
```

I want to output:

```
Home    Red
Home    Pink
Home    White
Car     Blue
Car     Yellow
Bike    Blue
```

What is the sql query I need to call to reorder the table this way? (This is in teradata, in case that made a difference).
I need to add that to each element in A, there may be associated one or more rows with the same elemt B, I want the distinct count.

Example:

```
Car     Blue
Car     Blue
Home    Red
Home    Pink
Home    Pink
Car     Yellow
Home    White
Bike    Blue
```

Should return the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one trick using `COUNT() OVER()` windowed aggregate funtion

```
select * from yourtable
Order by COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY A) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
order by count(distinct b) over (partition by a) desc
```

However, I don't think this works in Teradata:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a, b order by a) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to remove duplicates before the count. As `GROUP BY all columns` is the same as `DISTINCT` you can use this:

```
SELECT colA, colB
FROM tab
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY Count(*) Over (PARTITION BY colA) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
SELECT
col1,
col2
FROM (
SELECT
col1,
col2,
1 AS rn
FROM
<your table>) t
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,SUM(rn) DESC
```

That lets us get a "count" of the number of rows for each col1/col2 intersection.  It results in:

```
Bike    Blue
Car     Blue
Car     Yellow
Home    Pink
Home    Red
Home    White
```

Comment: But this is just a complicated way to do a `SELECT col1,col2 FROM tab GROUP BY 1,2 ORDER BY 1, COUNT(*) DESC`?